Minimal empty intersection of DFAs
I am pondering about this problem for a while now and haven't found anything related to it. Suppose we have a finite amount of deterministic finite automata $\{M_1, \dots, M_n\}$ that all recognize some language $L(M_i) \subseteq \Sigma^*$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$. Now suppose we are given that $L(M_1) \cap \dots \cap L(M_n) = \emptyset$. The goal is to now find the smallest non-empty subset $E \subseteq \{M_1, \dots, M_n\}$ such that the intersection of languages from the respective automata in $E$ is still empty.
I am not asking how to solve this problem, there are obvious naive ways to do this, and I am sure heuristics you can come up with. I am more wondering in what complexity class this problem lies. I have tried to look for similar looking problems in order to come up with reductions but I haven't really found anything that suited to this specific problem yet, or just haven't been able to create a smart reduction. I would like to find some other problem or way to determine how "hard" the problem is (I assume very hard, but I want to find a formal argument)
Maybe someone else has an idea? Many thanks in advance!

An upper bound for the complexity would be P-SPACE since you can explore the product automaton and look for the nimimal subset of accepting states that is not reachable.
You only need polynomial space since:

you can assume that every automaton has a single accepting state, by considering equivalent non-deterministic automaton with a single accepting state
then you build the product with a polynomial number of states ($|M_1|...|M_n|$)
you perform a a breadth-first search (or depth-first search) marking every reachable states
you check every non-reachable states saving on the fly the minimal set of final states (non empty). I mean you start with $n$ final states and whenever you find a non reachable state with at least one final state and less final state than what you remember than you keep this state.

For the lower bound I don't have the correct reduction yet but considering that the Intersection non-emptiness problem description is already PSPACE-complete  I think it wil be the same for you.
I hope my answer is clear enough ... Feel free to ask if you don't understand something. I'll keep thinking about a good lower bound.
